# Retrieve all of query containing semi-colons

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I'm trying to pull data from SQL via an ADODB recordset in VBA. I'm struggling to get results from each part of a SQL query when it contains semi-colons. Wondering if there's any way to do this without splitting my query into separate queries (to remove the semi-colon issue) and using separate recordsets for each.

See below for a simple example. When I run it, F2=1, G2=Failed - I want F2=1, G2=2.

```
' Sub to test using semi-colons in SQL queries
Sub getDataSimple0(server As String, database As String)

  ' Initialise variables
  Dim con As ADODB.Connection
  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

  Set con = New ADODB.Connection
  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

  ' Open Connection using Windows Authentication
  con.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & server & ";Initial Catalog=" & database & ";Trusted_connection=Yes;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;"
  con.Open

  ' Open recordset
  rs.Open "SELECT 1; SELECT 2", con

  ' Add data to worksheet
  Range("F2").CopyFromRecordset rs

  rs.NextRecordset
  If rs.State > adStateClosed Then
    Range("G2").CopyFromRecordset rs
  Else
    Range("G2").Value = "Failed"
  End If

  ' Close connection
  con.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to set the rs to the result of NextRecordset, so the code looks like this:

```
' Sub to test using semi-colons in SQL queries
Sub getDataSimple0(server As String, database As String)

  ' Initialise variables
  Dim con As ADODB.Connection
  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

  Set con = New ADODB.Connection
  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

  ' Open Connection using Windows Authentication
  con.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & server & ";Initial Catalog=" & database & ";Trusted_connection=Yes;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;"
  con.Open

  ' Open recordset
  rs.Open "SELECT 1; SELECT 2", con

  ' Add data to worksheet
  Range("F2").CopyFromRecordset rs

  Set rs = rs.NextRecordset
  If rs.State > adStateClosed Then
    Range("G2").CopyFromRecordset rs
  Else
    Range("G2").Value = "Failed"
  End If

  ' Close connection
  con.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go about it by doing something like the below.

```
' Sub to test using semi-colons in SQL queries
Sub getDataSimple0(server As String, database As String)

  ' Initialise variables
  Dim con As ADODB.Connection
  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim SQL_String As String
  Dim SQL_Array() As String
  Dim i As Integer

  Set con = New ADODB.Connection
  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

  ' Open Connection using Windows Authentication
  con.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & server & ";Initial Catalog=" & database & ";Trusted_connection=Yes;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;"
  con.Open

  'Multiple queries
  SQL_String = "SELECT 1; SELECT 2"

  'Split into array
  SQL_Array = Split(SQL_String, ";")

  'Add data to worksheet
  For i = LBound(SQL_Array) To UBound(SQL_Array)

     rs.Open SQL_Array(i), con
     Range("F2").Offset(0, i).CopyFromRecordset rs

  Next i


  ' Close connection
  con.Close

End Sub
```

Here I take the multiple queries and split them into an array that I loop over. Assuming that you want the ouptut in columns from column F and onward.

Comment: When I run this, G2 is blank (not 2). I think you need to add a `Set rs = rs.NextRecordset` (as suggested by Jonathan Willcock) under the `.CopyFromRecordset` line. The use of the array is nice, though. Appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: Ah, I see what you were getting at now, although I think you still need `rs.Close` after the `.CopyFromRecordset` to avoid an error

Comment: @hodgenovice, you are probably right about that. I didn't have the chance to test the code my self.